# Using tensorflow, can I back-propagate the already calculated gradients to all the parameters, and then apply the gradients to the whole network?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I can get the gradients w.r.t the outputs of the network(calculated by other ways), Can I just back-propagate the gradients to all the parameters, and then apply them to the whole network?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_model.py#L128).

```
trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
grads = tf.gradients(self.cost, trainable_variables)

if self.hps.optimizer == 'sgd':
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lrn_rate)
elif self.hps.optimizer == 'mom':
  optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(self.lrn_rate, 0.9)

apply_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(
    zip(grads, trainable_variables),
    global_step=self.global_step, name='train_step')
```

where you can replace the `gradients` if the gradients you calculated are also `tensors` or `variables`.

But if the gradients you calculated are numerical, I am not sure that tensorflow can easily do this.

Comment: I think, by this way, you should get all the grads and then apply them. but I can only have gradients for the last layer, what I want is first bp the last layer gradients to the preceding layers and get all the gradients, then I can apply them. Thank you!